# angular2-seed how to add a d.ts

Tags: angular

I am using angular2-seed, which I love. I am trying to add the `moment.js` library, but I would like to use it's d.ts file. I tried to run `typings install...` but that didn't seem to work. I noticed a folder `\tools\manual_typings\project`. Do I just add d.ts file there? Should I also run typinds install?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

```
npm install tsd -g
```

Then:

```
tsd install moment
```

Comment: I used typings instead of tsd. I think this is the new standard. But that didn't work. It seems like the angular2-seed needs something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
typings install moment --ambient
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11584526)

Comment: why? uksz wrote how to install it with tsd. as user2904713 stated "typings is the new standard". I provided an answer how to do it with typings.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the example in [angular2-seed-example-mashup](https://github.com/AngularShowcase/angular2-seed-example-mashup) and, with some minor changes, made it work.

Add this to typings.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "github:typed-typings/npm-moment#a4075cd50e63efbedd850f654594f293ab81a385",
```

Then go to `tools\config\seed.config.ts` (remember, this is for angular2-seed) and add 'moment/*': `${this.APP_BASE}node_modules/moment/moment`, to path of SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.

In the Component, import it `import * as moment from 'moment/moment';` and use it `var start = moment('2000 01 01', 'YYYY MM DD');`